# Does progress in The Magic Circle demo carry over to the main game?

Tags: the-magic-circle

There is a free demo of The Magic Circle available on Steam.

Is progress made in the demo carried over to the main game or will you have to start from the beginning again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, progress from the demo will be transferred to the main game when it is purchased. The developers stated that in [this announcement.](http://steamcommunity.com/games/323380/announcements/detail/43132055974758392)